# How to take control of user mouse movements when a user shares his screen through skype or MS teams?

Tags: python

I have used python code with pynput library and it worked fine to track my mouse movement in my system.
Our need is now to track the same mouse movements when user shares his screen through Skype/MS Teams ?

Please help.

We tried the below code.

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_move(x, y):
    pass
   # print('Pointer moved to {0}'.format(
    #    (x, y)))

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('{0} at {1}'.format(
        'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',
        (x, y)))
    if not pressed:
        # Stop listener
        return False

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    print('Scrolled {0} at {1}'.format(
        'down' if dy < 0 else 'up',
        (x, y)))

# Collect events until released
with mouse.Listener(
        on_move=on_move,
        on_click=on_click,
        on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    listener.join()

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = mouse.Listener(
    on_move=on_move,
    #on_click=on_click,
    on_scroll=on_scroll)
listener.start()
```

Comment: To be able to track the mouse movements through screen sharing is tricky. You probably need some sort of image analysis of the video itself to detect the mouse movement. Or, if the person trusts you, you can install a simple keylogger in his system, which he then sends you over the log files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any reference or sample code on this so that it will help us to understand @Axois

Comment: Unfortunately I've not tried this out yet, and I have no guarantee my proposed method will work. However, you can look into [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) and meanwhile, we will wait for someone with a better solution to answer.